# Find text in string and print multi results

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a long string result, for example:

```
<a href="#">aaa</a>
<a href="#">bbb</a>
<a href="#">ccc</a>
```

How do I search the string for '#">' and have an output of

```
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Would be good to say find '#' and print what is in between '>'  and '<'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you scraping this from a website or is this just a list of strings in an array?

Comment: Another question - would it be safe to say that every string fragment is in another line (as in your example)?

Comment: If you have the same tags: [i.split("<")[0] for i in a.split('<a href="#">') if "<" in i]

Comment: Yes, I am scraping from a website.

Comment: What are you using to scrape?

Comment: @Roy2012 They are all on one line....as in one long line

Comment: @JackRawlins Just using requests

Answer (score 1):

using the built in re library

```
import re

string = """<a href="#">aaa</a>
<a href="#">bbb</a>
<a href="#">ccc</a>"""

results = re.findall('href="#">(?P<data>[a-zA-Z]+)<', string)
```

You can adjust your regular expression search to suit your needs but this works with your example data.

Note that you may also want to consider an html parsing library like BeautifulSoup4 if you are doing more detailed html analysis.

Comment: What is the `?P<data>` for?

Comment: It is a group, so it just returns the data in between ( and )

Comment: Doesn't it do that just with the parenthesis?

Comment: For example `results = re.findall('href="#">(\w+)<', string)` yields the same result as far as I can tell

Comment: @Dan This is a named group. `data` is the name of the group. It can be fetched from the result either by index (1) or as a dictionary ['data']

Comment: Thanks @scotty3785

Comment: Yes, @scotty3785 is right.  It's useful if you want to search for multiple things that are near each other so I just use it by default when doing groups.  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The below will take the code from any webpage and return the contents of any a tags with a href value of #

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get('WEBSITE URL')

r = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

elements = soup.find_all('a')
for element in elements:
    b = element.attrs['href']
    if b == '#':
        print(element.contents)
```